# Migrating ArcGIS Server from 10.0 to 10.1 on Windows Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, installation, windows-server-2008

Due to the new system architecture of arcgis for server 10.1 I am first writing here to ask if anyone has successfully migrated from AGS 10.0 to 10.1 and what problems were encountered. I am currently serving data on Windows 2008 R2 with ArcGIS Server 10.0. I have about 20 map-client applications using aounrd 50 AGS services and no Fail-Save system. Around 400 People use the clients in my organisation.

As I am relatively new to ArcGIS server and the windows server environment (I was previously in an organisation which used Linux Ubuntu server,Apache, tomcat6, geoserver with PostgreSQL) I am quite worried about things not going to plan!

Comment: I need to update manually REST link in every code + I was facing port problem.. some times port 6080 blocked in some organizations/counties..I recommend you to go through the web help first

Comment: See the docs that Sunil references. Best case, if you can re-create the services from the original map documents in the same folder structure, you might be able to minimize the path changes in the apps if you do this. Afterwards, change the new server name to the old one if possible.

Answer (score 2):

As per your question Please go through the [web help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000002p0000000) and then tips on [ESRI blogs](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/05/29/welcome-arcgis-10-1-beta-a-few-tips-for-arcgis-server-migration/) plus follow the [jithens blog](http://geo.geek.nz/post/24991222710/its-important-to-plan-before-migrating-to-arcgis-for) for ArcGIS Server 10.1. Esri has released a special training course for that: [Migrating to ArcGIS 10.1 for Server](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.courseDetail&CourseID=50127141_10.x).

I went through all those articles.

Things to be take care:

1.arcgis folder

2.Security settings

3.Cached service

4.REST service urls ( Those need to update in various custom applications  like ArcGIS JSAPI, ArcGIS Flex  etc.)

**5.Please take backup and try this at down time.**

If any problem then please let us know.. all the best...